# How to convert pipe-separated text file to CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I have a big text file and i want to convert it into CSV using Python. My data looks like:

```
var1|var2|var3|tonumber|fromnumber|var|coding|udh|var|circle|var|var|var|var15

898980d1-6e5b-40f2-a313-c30f08bf0fe6|49A5919EB0D04EDE9B6CEB5AF932EAA3|sbs1|919899980898|HITECH|1|1|0|VODAFONE|Delhi|2015-02-21 12:08:51|5|3|RBA/6724R # Kailash Ram Panwar (PL) # Rz-410/13 Flat No-09 Iiird Floor Tkd Extn Delhi - 110019-110019 # Tgt Skt #  #
```

How can I convert this file to CSV? I tried:

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: piperows = []  

f = open("/home/suri/ValueFirst/MT.txt", "rb")

In [6]: readerpipe = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '|')

In [7]: for row in readerpipe: 
   ...:     piperows.append(row)
   ...:     f.close()  
   ...:
```

And I got the below error:

```
----------------------------------------------------
ValueError                      Traceback (most recent call last)  
<ipython-input-7-842b0d42f436> in <module>()  
----> 1 for row in readerpipe:  
      2     piperows.append(row)  
      3     f.close()  
      4   

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like @Martijn Pieters suggested, you should not have indented `f.close()` this way because it is now part of the loop. I would suggest using a with block, which will take care of automatically closing the file.

```
import csv

with open("/home/suri/ValueFirst/MT.txt", "rb") as f:
    readerpipe = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    piperows = list(readerpipe)
```

One thing here is that we build a big list of all the rows, which might be a bad idea if you are converting files. You could probably write the new comma-separated version, as you read the pipe-separated version.

```
import csv

with open("/home/suri/ValueFirst/MT.txt", "rb") as file_pipe:
    reader_pipe = csv.reader(file_pipe, delimiter='|')
    with open("/home/suri/ValueFirst/MT.csv", 'wb') as file_comma:
        writer_comma = csv.writer(file_comma, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader_pipe:
            writer_comma.writerow(row)
```

***Edit:*** @Martijn suggests to pass the reader directly to the writer's `writerows` method... If that `writerows` method is implemented correctly it will have the same effect and avoid loading all the rows in memory at once.

```
import csv

with open("/home/suri/ValueFirst/MT.txt", "rb") as file_pipe:
    reader_pipe = csv.reader(file_pipe, delimiter='|')
    with open("/home/suri/ValueFirst/MT.csv", 'wb') as file_comma:
        writer_comma = csv.writer(file_comma, delimiter=',')
        writer_comma.writerows(reader_pipe)
```

***Edit 2:*** The code becomes so simple that you could inline the reader and writer variables and get the following, if you like...

```
import csv

with open("/home/suri/ValueFirst/MT.txt", "rb") as file_pipe:
    with open("/home/suri/ValueFirst/MT.csv", 'wb') as file_comma:
        csv.writer(file_comma, delimiter=',').writerows(csv.reader(file_pipe, delimiter='|'))
```

Comment: i need a data like csv
it should look like:  
var       var1      var2     var3
xyt        cagf      sfgb     sgsg
afff       afgg      sggg    aggb

the above answer will give this kind of data?
please help me in this way

Comment: The code I proposed will change a file looking like `header1|header2|header3` `var1|var2|var3` into `header1,header2,header3` `var1,var2,var3`. If you need something different, please edit your question to make it clearer: that is more readable than inline comments ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the file after reading the first row:

```
for row in readerpipe: 
    piperows.append(row)
    f.close()
```

Remove the `f.close()` line from the loop.

Better still, use the file as a context manager so that it is closed automatically for you. You can simply call `list()` on the reader to produce your output list:

```
with open("/home/suri/ValueFirst/MT.txt", "rb") as f:
    readerpipe = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '|')
    piperows = list(readerpipe)
```

but to convert your file, you can pass in `readerpipe` straight into a `writer.writerows()` call:

```
with open("/home/suri/ValueFirst/MT.txt", "rb") as f:
    readerpipe = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '|')
    with open("/home/suri/ValueFirst/MT.txt", "wb") as outputfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
        writer.writerows(readerpipe)
```